# Efficiently replace numbers in list of strings with a token

Tags: python, pandas, cython

I have lists of strings where some of the strings are integers. I'd like to find a way to quickly replace numbers over 100 with a token based off the length of the numbers.

```
['foo', 'bar', '3333'] -> ['foo', 'bar', '99994']
```

I will be performing this operation millions of times over lists of length around 100. The pure python method I've come up with is as follows:

```
def quash_large_numbers(tokens, threshold=100):
    def is_int(s):
        try:
            int(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    BIG_NUMBER_TOKEN = '9999%d'
    tokens_no_high_nums = [BIG_NUMBER_TOKEN % len(t) if is_int(t) and int(t) > threshold else t
                           for t in tokens]
    return tokens_no_high_nums
```

I was trying to see if I could do this more quickly via `pandas`, but it's much slower for small lists, I imagine from all the overhead from converting back and forth from series to list.

```
def pd_quash_large_numbers(tokens, threshold=100):
    BIG_NUMBER_TOKEN = 9999
    tokens_ser = pd.Series(tokens)
    int_tokens = pd.to_numeric(tokens_ser, errors='coerce')
    tokens_over_threshold = int_tokens > threshold
    str_lengths = tokens_ser[tokens_over_threshold].str.len().astype(str)

    tokens_ser[tokens_over_threshold] = BIG_NUMBER_TOKEN + str_lengths

    return tokens_ser.tolist()
```

Is there a more efficient way I'm missing here? Possibly via cython?

Comment: What is your threshold requirement? You say 100... is it really a count of digits? There may be no need to convert to integer at all.

Comment: minor note: Your `is_int()` function is not needed since you can do: `isinstance(t, int)` or `isinstance(t, long)`

Comment: It's only a count of digits if the string can be cast to an integer. Don't think `isinstance` works as "3333" is a string.

Comment: I wouldn't expect much help from `Cython` because it can't bypass 2 basic Python objects (and their methods), lists and strings.  Cython doesn't have it's own string code; so it either has to work with `c` strings (awkward) or use capi calls to Python string methods.

Comment: One aside.  I think/hope that this is mostly a simplified example, as it seems like a terrible idea to use `"9999"` as the big number token.  Running your script two times on the same data would make every original number between 100 and 99,999,999,999 into `"99995"`, running it three times would make every number between `100`, and `10^100000 - 1` into `"99995"`.  Perhaps a prefix like `"~10^"` instead? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a nice speedup by counting text digits instead of doing any conversion. This test program knocked it down by nearly 80%. It runs the original code, my textual inspection code and piRSquared's numpy code. Let the best code win!

```
import time

# a thousand 100 item long lists to test
test_data = [['foo', 'bar', '3333'] * 33 for _ in range(1000)]

def quash_large_numbers(tokens, threshold=100):
    def is_int(s):
        try:
            int(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    BIG_NUMBER_TOKEN = '9999%d'
    tokens_no_high_nums = [BIG_NUMBER_TOKEN % len(t) if is_int(t) and int(t) > threshold else t
                           for t in tokens]
    return tokens_no_high_nums

start = time.time()
result = [quash_large_numbers(tokens, 100) for tokens in test_data]
print('original', time.time() - start)

def quash(somelist, digits):
    return [text if len(text) <= digits or not text.isdigit() else '9999' + str(len(text)) for text in somelist]

start = time.time()
result = [quash(item, 2) for item in test_data]
print('textual ', time.time() - start)

import numpy as np

def np_quash(somelist, threshold=100):
    v = np.array(somelist)
    r = np.arange(v.size)
    m = np.core.defchararray.isdigit(v)
    g = v[m].astype(int) > threshold
    i = r[m][g]
    t = np.array(['9999{}'.format(len(x)) for x in v[i].tolist()])
    v = v.astype(t.dtype)
    v[i] = t
    return v.tolist()

start = time.time()
result = [np_quash(item, 100) for item in test_data]
print('numpy   ', time.time() - start)
```

Results

```
original 0.6143333911895752
textual  0.12842845916748047
numpy    0.3644399642944336
```

Comment: Wow. Very impressive!

Comment: That is clever to avoid the numeric conversion altogether, I noticed you included `re` but didn't use it.  In my testing, `re` (.050s) was still faster than original (.207s) / numpy (.066s), but slower than `isdigit` (.027s)

Comment: I had an `re` test in there, but `isdigit` was faster. I'll remove that artifact.

Comment: I suspect that `isdigit` gets to C code so should be fast.

Answer (score 1):

***new quicker answer***

```
v = np.array(['foo', 'bar', '3333'])
r = np.arange(v.size)
m = np.core.defchararray.isdigit(v)
g = v[m].astype(int) > 100
i = r[m][g]
t = np.array(['9999{}'.format(len(x)) for x in v[i].tolist()])
v = v.astype(t.dtype)
v[i] = t
v.tolist()

['foo', 'bar', '99994']
```

***old answer***

```
s = pd.Series(['foo', 'bar', '3333'])
s.loc[pd.to_numeric(s, 'coerce') > 100] = s.str.len().map('9999{}'.format)

s

0      foo
1      bar
2    99994
dtype: object
```

Or

```
s.tolist()

['foo', 'bar', '99994']
```

Comment: Works but isn't any fast as I think maps are really slow.

Comment: @Luke Ok... I'm looking into it

Comment: @Luke I've provided another answer